# Why can't I use DirectorySearcher when importing function as a module

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, directorysearcher

When I try to use Import-Module of the function below I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "Det finns inte något sådant objekt på servern.
```

I have tried to return the `$Searcher` and then run `findAll()`, but I get the same result.
It works if I run the script directly or if I use the code in another script, but not when I use Import-Module.
(I replaced some parts of the code to make it more anonymous, like the server, port and password)

I tried to use dot-sourcing but still get tha same result. Other scripts work with both methods and I know it's loaded the function since the error is withing that function.
All data is passed to the function but the DirectorySearcher doesn't seem to work properly.

```
Function Search-HSA {
Param     (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $LDAPServer = "LDAP://[Server]:[port]/",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $LDAPSearchBase = "[Searchbase]",
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $LDAPFilter,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $LDAPSearchScope = "Subtree"
)
$Path = $LDAPServer + $LDAPSearchBase
$LDAPAuth = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Anonymous
$LDAPUser = "cn=user,ou=accounts,ou=admin,o=org,c=de"
$LDAPPassword = "[password]"
$LDAPObj = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Path, $LDAPUser, $LDAPPassword, $LDAPAuth)
$Properties = "*"
$Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($LDAPObj, $LDAPFilter)
$Searcher.PageSize = 1000
$Searcher.SearchScope = $LDAPSearchScope
$Properties | ForEach-Object { [void]$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($_) }
$Result = $Searcher.findAll()
Return $Result
} #End function
```

EDIT: I found the problem, I was using UTF-8 Encoding instead of UTF-16LE.

Comment: For a script file with function definitions alone (no module manifest), you'll want to dot-source it instead of calling `Import-Module`: `. .\path\to\Search-HSA.ps1`

Comment: I just tried with dot-source and I get the same result as if I was using Import-Module. I am using a module manifest where other imports work but this specific one does not.